# Visual Studio 2017 unable to make data connection dialog box

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2017

So I have the latest version of Visual Studios 2017 Professional. I have been trying to set up a data connection to an Access data file for development and have been unsuccessful doing so.

"The connection properties object must be of type OleDBAccessConnectionProperites."

Then after clicking OK, I get it again:

"The Connection properties object must be of type OleDBAccessConnectionProperties."

I never get the dialog box to add the needed information.

I am running 2012 Microsoft Server OS

The crazy part is, I have tried other data sources in this list and get the same reaction.

I have re-installed this version 4 time and 2 repairs and have been unsuccessful in making it work correctly.

The only time it has worked is when I add a non-default data source. Does anyone know how to repair/fix the default data source connection in order to get the correction next  dialog box to add my file information?

Answer (score 2):

There was an extra line in the machine.config file
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Config

right-click on machine.config and make a copy and change the object extension.

Then right-click on machine.config and open with notepad or notepad++

Found DbProvidersFactories listed twice, remove one

Then reopen visual studios